# Create POSTGRES table with VARCHAR[] in H2 in-memory database

Tags: h2, ddl

I have DDL for my PostgreSQL database. One of the columns in the table is of type `VARCHAR[]`. H2 fails to create this table, even if the database is running in PosgtreSQL compatibility mode (url: `jdbc:h2:mem:user-management;MODE=PostgreSQL`)

Simplified DDL:

```
create table "users" (
  "uuid" VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "roles" VARCHAR[] NOT NULL
);
```

Is there any data type that is compatible between H2 and PostgreSQL and is actually a varchar array? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered creating a `userRoles` table, with one row per user and one row per row.

Comment: That's how it should be done, and how I would do it. However, I just joined the project and it's already used on production. I know it's possible to migrate the data, but that's too much effort and risk. Moreover, different parties are also using, and it would break things for them.

Comment: By the way, if your field `uuid` is meant to store a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), know that both [H2](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#uuid_type) and [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) support UUID as a native data type (a 128-bit value) including for use as a primary key. Much more efficient that storing the text of the 32 or 36 character hex string representation of a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use array here, it's worked for me in h2 postgre mode.

```
create table "users" (
  "uuid" VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "roles" varchar array
);
```